# How do a library know whether the consumer implements a library interface and registers it in DI container?

Tags: c#, xamarin

I am learning Xamarin.Forms and trying to use DI with the following scenario.

The shared project (or library) has a DI-related class as follows.

```
public static class Startup
{
    public static ServiceProvider CreateServiceProvider(Action<IServiceCollection> nativeConfigureServices)
    {
        IServiceCollection isc = new ServiceCollection();

        nativeConfigureServices(isc);
        ConfigureServices(isc);

        return isc.BuildServiceProvider();
    }


    static void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection isc)
    {
        // others services are omitted for the sake of simplicity
        isc.AddTransient<MainPageViewModel>();
        isc.AddTransient<MainPage>();
        isc.AddSingleton<App>();
    }
}
```

`INativeCall` is an interface that can optionally be implemented by the consumer.

```
public interface INativeCall
{
    Task FloatMessage(string msg);
}
```

An instance of `INativeCall` is injected to  `MainPage` as follows.

```
public partial class MainPage : ContentPage
{
    private readonly INativeCall nativeCall;

    public MainPage(MainPageViewModel vm, INativeCall nativeCall)
    {
        InitializeComponent();

        // others are omitted for the sake of simplicity
        this.nativeCall = nativeCall;
    }


    private void Greeting_Clicked(object sender, System.EventArgs e)
    {
        nativeCall?.FloatMessage("I Love Xamarin.Forms");
    }
}
```

Then other OS-specific projects (Android, UWP, iOS) can optionally implement `INativeCall` and register it via `nativeConfigureServices`.

For the sake of simplicity, I choose an Android project as follows.

```
public class NativeCall : INativeCall
{
    public async Task FloatMessage(string msg)
    {
        Toast.MakeText(Application.Context, msg, ToastLength.Long).Show();
        await Task.CompletedTask;
    }
}
```

and

```
public class MainActivity : global::Xamarin.Forms.Platform.Android.FormsAppCompatActivity
{
    protected override void OnCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
    {
        // others have been removed for simplicity 

        ServiceProvider sp = Startup.CreateServiceProvider(isc =>
        {
            isc.AddSingleton<INativeCall, NativeCall>();
        });

        LoadApplication(sp.GetRequiredService<App>());
    }
}
```

## Question

If the consumer (Android project above) neither implements `INativeCall` nor registers it in the DI container, how can I modify

```
private void Greeting_Clicked(object sender, System.EventArgs e)
{
    nativeCall?.FloatMessage("I Love Xamarin.Forms");
}
```

to get rid of runtime errors?

> System.InvalidOperationException: 'Unable to resolve service for type 'INativeCall' while attempting to activate 'MainPage'.'

In other words, how do a library know whether the consumer implements a library interface and registers it in DI container?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> System.InvalidOperationException: 'Unable to resolve service for type
>   'INativeCall' while attempting to activate 'MainPage'.'

This is the container indicating that `MainPage` has a constructor dependency that it was unable to satisfy.

The simplest solution is generally to change:

```
public MainPage(MainPageViewModel vm, INativeCall nativeCall)
```

to:

```
public MainPage(MainPageViewModel vm, INativeCall nativeCall = null)
```

to indicate that the dependency is optional.

*This will require all usages of `nativeCall` in the class to do `null` checks though (since `nativeCall` may, or may not, have been provided). Like you are already doing with `nativeCall?.FloatMessage("I Love Xamarin.Forms");`*